# combine layers in qgis

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, point, path

I have a Shapefile that includes country divisions (Polygon). I have another Shapfile  that relates to the country's roadmap (Path). I also have another Shapfile  that relates to the village points (Points). How can I separate a part of the  Shapfile  for geographic divisions, which includes path and Points?

Comment: A shapefile can either hold points, lines or polygons, not a combination of those. Would a different file format be an option for you? If so, please update the question.

Comment: I do not know if it is of much help but check out 'Multipolygons' which can hold more than 1 polygons.